# good and bad alpha-blank screenshot catching

Tags: android, adb, wifi, screenshot, alpha

I have several tv-boxes, working via wi-fi in different city points - show video ads. To check they are show video correctly, I decide to take screenshots with some interval and compare them. Ok, I take screenshot by this command:

```
adb shell screencap -p /sdcard/screen.png && adb pull /sdcard/screen.png
```

sometimes I get good screen shot: picture from screen like this
[Good screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2LGf.png)
but sometimes I get this:
[like alpha-channel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBAdN.png)
Picture from desktop [monitor view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chTKX.jpg)
I testing one box in office, and it have the same bugs. Videos plays this way:

```
Intent localIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MediaObjectPlayerActivity.class);
                localIntent.putExtra("path", localPath);
                localIntent.putExtra("name", mCurrentPlay);
                localIntent.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(localIntent);
```

What can be wrong ? What is anomaly behavior ? Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if you want to catch screenshot of video from VideoView, you need to use MediaMetadataRetriever. Here is good example http://android-er.blogspot.ru/2016/04/capture-frames-in-videoview-using.html